# What device is universal for electrostatics?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, coulombs-law, electrical-engineering

In [The varieties of material existence](http://cognitivemedium.com/vme), Michael Nielsen says the following:

"It’s easy to design a programmable device which is universal for electrostatics in any given closed region of space. You need two abilities: (1) the ability to create arbitrary charge densities within the region; and (2) a set of electrodes bounding the space, to which can be applied arbitrary potentials. Standard results about boundary-value problems then imply that both: (1) the electric field is completely determined within the region; and (2) any electric field which is possible in electrostatics may be created in this way. It should, in fact, be relatively easy to build a crude prototype for such a system, although of course there will be limits on the achievable charge densities and potentials. (**I wouldn’t be surprised if this was routine, and I simply don’t know the name of this type of device**.)".

Does this device exist? What's it's name?

Comment: after a little research, I decided that I was not smart enough to figure out what he is trying to accomplish. He certainly has an impressive resume though.

Comment: @VictoryOmole *universal for electrostatics*...can you plz. elaborate on that?

Comment: @lineage The term 'universal' is borrowed from computer science; where for example, a universal computer can perform any algorithm with enough time and memory. 'universal for electrostatics'; i can only repeat the question, means the ability to create arbitrary charge densities within a closed region of space and with a set of electrodes around that space, being able to apply arbitrary potentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The device is not possible.

It is not possible due to Earnshaw's Theorem: a collection of charges cannot be maintained in a stable equilibrium *solely* by electrostatic forces. That means that, if you want to put a charge somewhere and keep it there, you *are required to have* either a magnetic field or an AC electric field. Neither of these fits in the "universal electrostatics" bill. (As an aside, this is exactly the logic that leads to the Paul and Penning traps of ion trapping.)

But let's keep going anyway; let's suppose your author is okay with having to use some other type of field (which I'll now be calling "external fields"), so long as he can get arbitrary electrostatic potentials on the walls and arbitrary static charges inside. Then we could *in theory* do these things; can they be implemented in practice?

I'm imagining a couple of possible models. The key is that you need something to carry the charge. Charge doesn't just *exist* on its own. You need mass onto which it's attached. And you need things that can carry both positive and negative charge densities (to fit the word "arbitrary"). There are several ways you could go with this, but all of them are constrained by quantum mechanics.

One model is using loose particles, such as atoms properly ionized or, say, protons and electrons. Now, understand that *producing* these particles takes some work by atomic standards. Particularly in the ion case, it becomes extremely difficult to accurately produce ions with charges over $|q|=2e$ or $3e$. And if either the ions or the loose subatomic particles interact with any air molecules, they will be lost, so for any hope at a reasonable production rate, you'll need some kind of vacuum system. Even if you have a vacuum system, the metals in the vacuum system will interact with the charges, and you may end up with contaminants from collision processes (I'm not sure what at rate this would occur, though). But the *real* issue is getting the particles *into* your chamber. As you say, you need to be able to create arbitrary potentials *on the walls* of the chamber. But now we're saying we need a hole in one of the walls for these particles to come in. Do you leave the hole open? Your particles may very well just escape. Do you try to close the hole? A moving part in a vacuum chamber is a *terrible* idea, because either the pieces grind together and knock off contaminating atoms, or they're not close enough together, and air gets in.

Assuming you could somehow solve all of these technical problems, you would then have to actually apply the right fields. On a uniform conductor, charges will spread out uniformly, so having solid walls is a no-go. You could construct walls from a sort of checkerboard of conductor and insulator (or some other more fruitful pattern) to isolate each conductor. The issue then is being able to adequately control each conductor; to create these potentials you have to *apply* the voltage to the conductor. That would be a technical nightmare for *any* size of chamber that gets a reasonably good resolution of potential. And that's just for your electrostatic potential, the one you actually want; you'll *also* need to do this for your external field to get the kind of control you want to keep your charges in their stable configurations.

And speaking of those configurations... my guess is that it's frankly not possible to find the right configuration of external fields to hold an arbitrary set of charges in place, at least not when the field is applied externally to the box.

You could try an alternate model where you do a doping-like process as they do in semiconductors. Then you're working with a solid, which is *far* from arbitrary. But you could in principle produce something where you replace some of the atoms of, say, a silicon slab with dopants like gallium, which would have fewer or more electrons in the valence shell than silicon. These make the solid want to return to the right number of electrons, which creates charge densities. However, I suspect you couldn't make this very big, either, and the precision required to get arbitrary charge densities would be prohibitive. Furthermore, the interior fields of these solids are not incredibly well understood, but it is known that those fields are determined by the structure of the solid; so you're in the saddest place possible, where you don't have enough quantitative information to take advantage of it, but you have enough qualitative information to know that you're not really going to be able to take that much advantage of it, anyway. Furthermore, the charge densities you could reach are likely not very high, as you would begin to create other effects, and eventually dielectric breakdown would occur.

All of this is to say that either the device is prohibited by the laws of physics; or the device is prohibited by mathematics; or the device is *extraordinarily* technically challenging to build in a way that is at all useful.

In short, not only is the device not routine, but I suspect it does not exist at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy enough to produce an electric field of "arbitrary" strength and direction in a closed region: two plates of a capacitor separated by vacuum would do it. Charge density on the plates can be "arbitrary" (just vary the voltage between the plates).  What we *do not* have a way to do is "create arbitrary charge densities *within* the region".  If we could, just for an instant, put charges in specific locations within a *volume* of space, they would instantly blow apart because of mutual electrostatic repulsion.

It is possible to trap charge within a dielectric medium, and (in principle) construct a predetermined position-dependent charge density within a volume, but the amount of charge, or the charge gradient, can't be much or dielectric breakdown occurs and the charge distribution flattens and dissipates.

Perhaps Neilsen meant to say something like "create arbitrary charge densities on the boundary of the region".  This would be difficult, but not impossible.

Near as I can see, Neilsen is speculating that life and consciousness might be constructible from a lot of different substrates other than organic molecules, and it appears that he mentioned this "arbitrary charge density" to suggest that arrangements of charge might provide an alternative substrate.  Maybe, maybe not--  it's not science yet, it's not technology yet, -- and it's not even possible in principle (yet).  It's just fun speculation.

Answer (score 0):

I also am not completely sure what you're asking, but here is a possible approximation to an answer:

Wherever you want a charge inside the region, put an electret there. To hold it in position while minimally affecting the region, attach it to two or more nonconducting strings that get tied to something stable. The strings will be at least a little bit stretchy so your electret might wind up vibrating at some characteristic frequency. I hope that's acceptable.

To some extent you can change the fields by machining your electrets to peculiar shapes, and also vary the charge density in them.

Setting up electrodes around your volume should not be an issue.

Surround the whole thing with a faraday cage.

You're limited in how strong you can make the electrets, and how efficient your faraday cage is. If you know the locations of the charges and their intensities, you should be able to calculate the strengths of the fields, at least on a macro scale.

I don't have a name for it either.